# D3 stack Streamgraph not curvy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was attempting to recreate this d3 [Stream Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954) with version 4. I was following the documentation on [Stacks](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stacks). Based upon my data set, I'm not understanding why my graph is not curvy.

[image]

I'm using the sample data set:

```
var data = [
  {month: new Date(2015, 0, 1), apples: 3840, bananas: 1920, cherries: 960, dates: 400},
  {month: new Date(2015, 1, 1), apples: 1600, bananas: 1440, cherries: 960, dates: 400},
  {month: new Date(2015, 2, 1), apples:  640, bananas:  960, cherries: 640, dates: 400},
  {month: new Date(2015, 3, 1), apples:  320, bananas:  480, cherries: 640, dates: 400}
...
];
```

And i perform the following:

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries", "dates"])
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetWiggle);

var series = stack(data);
```

A `console.log(series)` produces this array:

```
[
    [[0,3840],[2059,3659],[3266,3906],[3892,4212]],
    [[3840,5760],[3659,5099],[3906,4866],[4212,4692]],
    [[5760,6720],[5099,6059],[4866,5506],[4692,5332]],
    [[6720,7120],[6059,6459],[5506,5906],[5332,5732]]
    ...
]
```

I create my `x` and `y` domains and ranges like this:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.month; }))
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(series, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d){ return d[0] + d[1];}); })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#51D0D7", "#31B5BB"]);
```

Trying to stack the graphs with d3.area()

```
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

// I get stuck here:
var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(series)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style("fill", function() { return color(Math.random()); });
```

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4etr9pyd/2/) with the code, but it's not showing up curvy as the example. I've set the offset to be `d3.stackOffsetWiggle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display data across time, then you should use a time scale for the x axis.

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.month; }))
  .range([0, width]);
```

Also, the `stack` function returns the `y0` (the bottom) and `y1` (the top) positions of each layer and you are using those values incorrectly. Here's how they should be used in the area builder:

```
var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
  .y0(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
```

And here's [your fixed JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4etr9pyd/3/).

EDIT: Since this answer you've edited your question. To make a stacked area chart "curvy", you need to add [a curve](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#area_curve) to your area builder, like this:

```
var area = d3.area()
  ...
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
```

Check the [curves documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) for all the available curves.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've figured that out, updated my question and my JSFiddle. I've altered the fiddle and created a new one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4etr9pyd/2/). Do you know why my Streamgraph isn't curvy?

Comment: Why don't i see a curve on the example graph that Mike created?

Comment: Because that graph is built using D3 v3, where the API is different. In that version, `.offset("wiggle")` makes the graph curvy.

Comment: Also, good job in figuring out what was wrong with the area builder! You almost did not need our help :)

Comment: Thanks. I was misinterpreting how the stack worked, but after reading it a few times I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a different curve to make the lines smooth and not just polylines.

See the [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4etr9pyd/4/).

```
var area = d3.area()
.x(function(d) { console.info('in area function', d); return x(d.data.month); })
.y0(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
.y1(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
.curve(d3.curveBasis);
```

The last line sets the curve function. You can find more [curve functions here](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves).

Comment: Why don't i see a curve on the example graph that Mike created?